# printf("%s Buffer[k]",buffer[k],k); Only prints > buffer not %s

Tags: c

I'm making a puzzle game so I want to write word uppercase when user found that word. So I wrote this loop but it isn't working. Program isn't getting into IF statement. I've tried to print `printf("%s Buffer[k]",buffer[k],k);` in the second for (i) to find the problem but I didn't see words , program only printed " Buffer[0] \n Buffer[1] \n ..........Buffer[9]".
                       But when I printed these `printf("%s Buffer[k]",buffer[k],k);` in first loop it printed correctly. How can I fix this?
and my second question is:
Why it isn't get into IF statement?

CODE 1:

```
for(int k=0; k<MAX_WORD_NUMBER; k++){
            for(int i=0; i<MAX_WORD_LENGTH; i++){
                printf("%s Buffer[k]",buffer[k],k);
                if(strcmp(buffer[k],word) == 0){                    
                    buffer[k][i] = word[i] - 32;
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Buffer[0]
Buffer[1]
.
.
.
Buffer[8]
Buffer[9]
```

CODE 2:

```
for(int k=0; k<MAX_WORD_NUMBER; k++){
     printf("%s Buffer[k]",buffer[k],k);
        for(int i=0; i<MAX_WORD_LENGTH; i++){
            if(strcmp(buffer[k],word) == 0){                    
                buffer[k][i] = word[i] - 32;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
wall Buffer[0]
evasive Buffer[1]
. 
.
.
war Buffer[9]
```

Comment: There is something wrong in the print statement you described in your post (by the way, please add it your code so we can figure out exactly what you have tried.).
A correct use of the print is :
`printf("%s Buffer[%d]",buffer[k],k);`

Comment: I've changed @Hayfa

Comment: You write that output rows are like `Buffer[0]`. You probably meant ` Buffer[0]`, didn't you? (Note the leading space). It probably means that `buffer[k]` is an empty string (or just starts with a 0).

Comment: You indicate that a solution has been found to your question by accepting an answer.  You're allowed to answer your own question, so rather than editing the question to say "solved", post your own answer then accept it once the system allows you to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[SOLVED]
**I've changed MAX_WORD_LENGTH to strlen(word) and strncmp instead of strcmp**